# LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session I don't have session

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting LazyInitializationException and not sure why. Here is the code:
`Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "autoCompleteContact.show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String autoCompleteAccount(
            @RequestParam(value = "q") String q,
            @RequestParam(value = "limit") int limit,
            @RequestParam(value = "timestamp") Long timestamp,
            @RequestParam(value = "studyIds") List<Long> studyIds,
            Authentication auth, ModelMap model) {

        try {

            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication();
            User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

            List<Contact> contacts = shareImageService.getAllContacts(user);
            String autoCompleteStr = "";
            int newLimit = contacts.size(); // > limit ? limit : contacts.size();
            boolean isNetworkStudy = shareImageService.isNetworkStudy(user, studyIds);
```

`shareImageService.isNetworkStudy`:

```
public boolean isNetworkStudy(User user, List<Long> studyIds) {
        for (Long studyId : studyIds) {
            StudyShareAccess access = shareService.getStudyShareAccessStatus(studyId, user);
        ...
    }
```

`shareService.getStudyShareAccessStatus`:

```
public StudyShareAccess getStudyShareAccessStatus(Long studyId, User actor) {
       ...
       if (isStudyBelongsToActor(study, actor.getPrimaryAccount())) {
       ...
```

`getStudyShareAccessStatus()`:

```
private boolean isStudyBelongsToActor(Study study, Account actor) {
        boolean isOwnStudy = false;
        if (actor != null && study != null) {
            if (study.getIbId().equals(actor.getRepository().getIbId())) {
                isOwnStudy = true;
            }
        }
        return isOwnStudy;
    }
```

Lastly, `Account` and `Repository` classes have .hbm files. Here is Repository files:

```
public class Repository implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Long id;
    private Account account;
    private Long ibId;
    private String name;
    ...
```

`Repository.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Nov 18, 2009 9:09:09 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.4.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.accelarad.data.mapping.account.Repository" table="SMR_REPOSITORIES" >
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="sequence" >
                <param name="sequence_name">SMR_REPOSITORIES_ID_SEQ</param>
                <param name="sequence">SMR_REPOSITORIES_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <!-- property name="accountId" type="long">
            <column name="ACCOUNT_ID" not-null="true" />
        </property -->
        <property name="ibId" type="long">
            <column name="IB_ID" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        ...
```

Error is coming from actor.getRepostiory().**getIbid()**. Since `Account` and `Repository` is from hibernate, I think the cause of exception is because hibernate session is closed when I am trying to access `Ibid` of `Repository`.

However, I have no idea how to fix this issue. I found one solution by turning on enable_lazy_load_no_trans, but I found this is anti pattern. I am not really opening any session so I don't know how to open a session. I am new to hibernate and this code wasn't written by me so I am having trouble understanding how to resolve this error.

Comment: You can try adding `@Transactional` annotation to your method `getStudyShareAccessStatus`. When the method is invoked a transaction will be created which will then commit (or rollback if an exception is raised) when the method is exited.
This should stop your Hibernate session from being closed when trying to access the `ibId` field of `Repository`.

Comment: I will try that.. does it also close the hibernate session after the transaction as well? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, the session will close along with the transaction.

Comment: Could you see if this helps https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/ You might need to fetch ibidI information before trying to access it.

Comment: `@Transactional` did not work

Comment: @SusanMustafa I read through the article but the problem is I am not using any query so I can't modify the query. I understand I need to load the object but not sure how to.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you use Spring Transactional and did you set it on your public method?